# gwtp overrides relative url

Tags: gwtp, gwt-platform

I've started new project with gwt 2.7 and gwtp 1.4
I have some relative path for my application:

"127.0.0.1:8080/studyext"

I have two places defined:

```
public static final String home = "Home";
public static final String newStudy = "New";
```

"Home" is my default place. When I'm requesting some place, my URL is changed ignoring relative deployment path of my application:

"127.0.0.1:8080/New"

I have two questions:
1) I'm expecting to get "127.0.0.1:8080/studyext/New" and not "127.0.0.1:8080/New". What I'm doing wrong?

2) How can I enable old stile tokens? Like "127.0.0.1:8080/studyext#New"

Comment: How are you revealing the new place? Both the parameter token formatter (old style) and route token formatter use the hash (#).

Comment: Hi, thank you for reply. I have simple link menu to reveal nested presenters:

Comment: <g:HTMLPanel>
        <g:InlineHyperlink targetHistoryToken="{nameTokens.getHome}">Home</g:InlineHyperlink>
        |
        <g:InlineHyperlink targetHistoryToken="{nameTokens.getNewStudy}">New</g:InlineHyperlink>
        |
        <g:InlineHyperlink targetHistoryToken="{nameTokens.getMyStudies}">Studies</g:InlineHyperlink>
    </g:HTMLPanel>

Comment: When I'm trying to navigate to "New" link. Getting "127.0.0.1:8080/New" instead of "127.0.0.1:8080/studyext/New"

Comment: That's unusual. `targetHistoryToken` should update the hash. Do you have any libraries like gwt-pushstate in your source paths?

Comment: Hmmm. Yes it is! I've creates skeleton for project using gwtp eclipse plugin. And gwt-pushstate is there. Can you explain please how it affects url structure?

Comment: Yep, I've removed it and I'm getting exactly what I'm expecting. Thanks a lot! I will read gwt-pushstate documentation.